# How to solve 503 error for mysql server on AWS lightsail LAMP stack

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, bitnami, amazon-lightsail, http-status-code-503

I currently have an AWS bitnami lampstack hosted at [www.spidercartographers.co.uk](http://www.spidercartographers.co.uk). The issue is that I keep getting a 503 error from the API at [www.spidercartographers.co.uk/api](http://www.spidercartographers.co.uk/api) which runs on a mysql database. I have tried restarting mysql, apache and rebooting the instance but none seem to solve this issue. Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: HTTP 503 = Common causes are a server that is down for maintenance or that is overloaded

Comment: How would I find out whether it is down or overloaded?

Comment: You can get more information from the Apache's log (/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/error_log)